# Two buttons, only one works

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Only one out of my two “Order Now” buttons seems to work. Can’t find out the issue. The link and the `:hover` function works for the first button but for the second one none of them works. The first button is `showcasebutton` and the second one is `showcasebutton2`. They use the same code in CSS but it still isn’t working.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  }
  else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(10, 10, 104, 0.068), rgba(89, 85, 150, 0.247)), url(imgs/teslamodely.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0%;
  padding-right: 42px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.logo {
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 48px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 125px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.description {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
}

nav.black {
  background: rgba(126, 114, 145, 0.61);
}

.trustbadge {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#model_s {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#model_3 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #11232F;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box.hover>.search-txt {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #017CC9;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #11232F;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-btn>i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#searchbtnpic {
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
}

* {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

.showcasebutton {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.showcasebutton:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

#buttonid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  align-content: center;
}

.nametext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.showcasebutton2 {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.showcasebutton2:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

#buttonid2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img class="logo" src="imgs/Tesla_logo.png">
    </a>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search....">
        <a class="search-btn" href="">
          <img id="searchbtnpic" src="imgs/searchbtn.png" alt="">
          <i class="fas fa-search">
                        </i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1>Model Y</h1>
  <div id="buttonid">
    <a href="cart.html">
      <button type="button" class="showcasebutton">Order Now</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <img id="model_s" src="imgs/Tesla_model_S.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="nametext">
    <h1>Model S</h1>
    <div id="buttonid2">
      <a href="cart.html">
        <button type="button" class="showcasebutton2">Order Now</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<img id="model_3" src="imgs/model_3.png" alt="">
```

Comment: First of all: You forgot to close the html tag. Second: if you want to style elements use a <style> Tag in the head and add your css code in the style-tag

Comment: What do you mean by “working”? The gray background doesn’t cover the lower button, but the button itself looks fine.

Comment: First of all, when you click the button, you don't go to where it is linked to. Second of all, the :hover is supposed to change the look of the button, but that doesn't happen when you hover over it.

Comment: I think You can't see it because of the background color. you look over here https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-maxwell-86uyv?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

I added a `container` class and deleted the `nametext` class.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  }
  else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(10, 10, 104, 0.068), rgba(89, 85, 150, 0.247)), url(imgs/teslamodely.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0%;
  padding-right: 42px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.logo {
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 48px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 125px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.description {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
}

nav.black {
  background: rgba(126, 114, 145, 0.61);
}

.trustbadge {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#model_s {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#model_3 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #11232F;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box.hover>.search-txt {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #017CC9;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #11232F;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-btn>i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#searchbtnpic {
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
}

* {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

.showcasebutton {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.showcasebutton:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

#buttonid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  align-content: center;
}



.showcasebutton2 {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.showcasebutton2:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

#buttonid2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.container{
   position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    align-content: center; 
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height: auto;
    background: #2421fe;
    display: block;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img class="logo" src="imgs/Tesla_logo.png">
    </a>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search....">
        <a class="search-btn" href="">
          <img id="searchbtnpic" src="imgs/searchbtn.png" alt="">
          <i class="fas fa-search">
                        </i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1>Model Y</h1>
  <div id="buttonid">
    <a href="cart.html">
      <button type="button" class="showcasebutton">Order Now</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <img id="model_s" src="imgs/Tesla_model_S.jpg" alt="">
 <div>
     <h1>Model S</h1>
    <div id="buttonid2">
      <a href="cart.html">
        <button type="button" class="showcasebutton2">Order Now</button>
      </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<img id="model_3" src="imgs/model_3.png" alt="">
```